# Select Only One Row, by Value Field, Ordering

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, rownum

This Question extends from [Oracle SQL Where Conditions weight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59777031/1410223) but, is more general (without product restriction, but give one by product value).

I have a table

```
DROP TABLE mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable 
(
    product_code VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    priority NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    date_act DATE, 
    date_dis DATE
);
```

Populate the table

```
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act, date_dis) VALUES ('bla', '0', TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2019-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act, date_dis) VALUES ('bla', '1', TO_DATE('2019-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2019-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act) VALUES ('bla', '2', TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act) VALUES ('bla', '3', TO_DATE('2019-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_dis) VALUES ('bla', '4', TO_DATE('2019-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_dis) VALUES ('bla', '5', TO_DATE('2019-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority) VALUES ('bla', '6');
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority) VALUES ('bla', '7');

INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act, date_dis) VALUES ('foo', '0', TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2019-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act) VALUES ('foo', '1', TO_DATE('2019-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_dis) VALUES ('foo', '2', TO_DATE('2019-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority) VALUES ('foo', '3');


INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act, date_dis) VALUES ('tmp', '0', TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2019-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_act) VALUES ('tmp', '1', TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority, date_dis) VALUES ('tmp', '2', TO_DATE('2019-02-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
INSERT INTO mytable (product_code, priority) VALUES ('tmp', '3');
```

The content

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

And Output

```
PRODUCT_CODE           PRIORITY DATE_ACT  DATE_DIS 
-------------------- ---------- --------- ---------
bla                           0 01-JAN-19 31-JAN-19
bla                           1 01-FEB-19 28-FEB-19
bla                           2 01-JAN-19          
bla                           3 01-FEB-19          
bla                           4           31-JAN-19
bla                           5           28-FEB-19
bla                           6                    
bla                           7                    
foo                           0 01-JAN-19 31-JAN-19
foo                           1 01-FEB-19          
foo                           2           31-JAN-19
foo                           3                    
tmp                           0 01-JAN-19 31-JAN-19
tmp                           1 01-JAN-19          
tmp                           2           28-FEB-19
tmp                           3
```

Condition definitions

- *condition_weight 4*: When the row has `date_act` and `date_dis` defined.
- *condition_weight 3*: When the row has `date_dis` defined but `date_act` not.
- *condition_weight 2*: When the row has `date_act` defined but `date_dis` not.
- *condition_weight 1*: When the row has `date_act` and `date_dis` not defined.

If condition_weight 4 is true the left (3, 2 and 1) will be ignored.

If condition_weight 4 is false and condition_weight 3 is true , condition_weight 2 and condition_weight 1 will be ignored.

If condition_weight 4 and 3 are false and condition_weight 2 is true condition_weight 1 will be ignored.

If condition_weight 4, 3 and 2 are false only condition_weight 1 will be evaluated.

**THE QUESTION:** How obtain only one row by each `product_code` with its ***priority highest***, with input parameter date_submit with condition weight definitions?

**EXAMPLE of OUTPUT Required** *NOTE*: The below table results are created manually (I need similar results, but I don't have the query).

**DATE_SUBMIT :='2019/01/15'**

```
CONDITION_WEIGHT       PRIO PRODUCT_CODE           PRIORITY DATE_ACT  DATE_DIS  :DATE_SUBMIT                                                                                                                    
---------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- --------- --------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               4          0 bla                           0 01-JAN-19 31-JAN-19 2019/01/15                                                                                                                      
               4          0 foo                           0 01-JAN-19 31-JAN-19 2019/01/15                                                                                                                      
               4          0 tmp                           0 01-JAN-19 31-JAN-19 2019/01/15
```

**DATE_SUBMIT :='2019/02/15'**

```
CONDITION_WEIGHT       PRIO PRODUCT_CODE           PRIORITY DATE_ACT  DATE_DIS  :DATE_SUBMIT                                                                                                                    
---------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- --------- --------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               4          1 bla                           1 01-FEB-19 28-FEB-19 2019/02/15                                                                                                                      
               2          1 foo                           1 01-FEB-19           2019/02/15                                                                                                                      
               3          2 tmp                           2           28-FEB-19 2019/02/15
```

**DATE_SUBMIT :='2018/12/31'**

```
CONDITION_WEIGHT       PRIO PRODUCT_CODE           PRIORITY DATE_ACT  DATE_DIS  :DATE_SUBMIT                                                                                                                    
---------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- --------- --------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               3          5 bla                           5           28-FEB-19 2018/12/31                                                                                                                      
               3          2 foo                           2           31-JAN-19 2018/12/31                                                                                                                      
               3          2 tmp                           2           28-FEB-19 2018/12/31
```

**DATE_SUBMIT :='2019/12/31'**

```
CONDITION_WEIGHT       PRIO PRODUCT_CODE           PRIORITY DATE_ACT  DATE_DIS  :DATE_SUBMIT                                                                                                                    
---------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- --------- --------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               2          3 bla                           3 01-FEB-19           2019/12/31                                                                                                                      
               2          1 foo                           1 01-FEB-19           2019/12/31                                                                                                                      
               2          1 tmp                           1 01-JAN-19           2019/12/31
```

Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779653/1410223 result, but if is it possible more simpler Query.

**EDIT** Only `priority` with highest `priority` must be .

Comment: . . Referring to another question is not going to help anyone understand the question that *you* have here.  I would suggest that you explain the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign condition weights using `case when`. Then take best row for each product, use `rank()`:

```
with 
  d as (select date '2019-02-15' date_submit from dual),
  t as (
    select m.*, case 
                when date_act is not null and date_dis is not null then 4 
                when date_act is null and date_dis is not null then 3
                when date_act is not null and date_dis is null then 2
                else 1 end condition
      from mytable m)
select product_code, priority, date_act, date_dis, condition, date_submit 
  from (
    select t.*, d.*, 
           rank() over ( partition by product_code order by condition desc ) rnk
      from t join d 
        on date_submit between nvl(date_act, date_submit) and nvl(date_dis, date_submit))
  where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, the `priority` must be Keeping in mind. (I need only One row with  the higher priority).

Comment: for works changing to  `rank() over ( partition by product_code order by condition desc, priority desc) rnk` inserting --> `, priority desc`

Comment: So add priority to `order by` as You did, but why is it `desc`? Shouldn't be priority ascending, 1 before 3? In that case use `order by condition desc, priority asc`.

Comment: I wan't to say (Hi Priority, Hi its value).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want.

```
select *
from (
    SELECT mytable.*,
        case when date_act is not null and date_dis is not null then 4
                 when date_dis is not null then 3
                 when date_act is not null then 2
                 else 1 end as weight,
        max(case when date_act is not null and date_dis is not null then 4
                 when date_dis is not null then 3
                 when date_act is not null then 2
                 else 1 end) over (partition by product_code) as max_weight
    FROM mytable
    where TO_DATE(:date_submit, 'yyyy/mm/dd') between coalesce(date_act, TO_DATE(:date_submit, 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
                        and coalesce(date_dis, TO_DATE(:date_submit, 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
    ) iv
where weight = max_weight
;
```

It would be a little simpler if you also wanted to filter by the `:product_code` parameter, like in your other question.

Comment: Sorry, the `priority` must be Keeping in mind. (I need only One row with  the higher priority).